# can't debug mobile native app with tizen studio ide

Tags: debugging, tizen, connection-timeout, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

I have tizen studio ide v1.0.2 installed. I created a new project from one of the samples (sensors). It builds ok. But I can't debug or run it. When I start either run or debug, the emulator window shows up, and eventually it says "Starting the kernel". The ide shows "Launching Sensor Debug", and gets to 81%, then it times out making a connection to the emulator - an error box pops up. Closing it leaves the emulator window open and I have to use the task manager to end it the emulator.

Any pointers, etc. will be greatly appreciated.

TIA

ken

Comment: Share the error message in the pop-up window.

Comment: `Timeout occurred while waiting for connection from the emulator.` I get this message in a log file:  *!ENTRY org.tizen.common.connection.toolbar.EmulatorLaunchWorker 4 0 2017-01-07 12:11:48.091
!MESSAGE [2017.01.07 12:11:48][ERROR] EmulatorLaunchWorker.java(73) - Timeout to wait for emulator booting done
*

Comment: Please share the screenshot of the emulator after launching it and try with creating a new emulator deleting the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Open Emulator Manager (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>) under Tools. Check HD Mobile (assuming that is your platform), Click Edit, Under device uncheck all the sensors that you DON'T NEED.

Click Confirm.

Now LAUNCH EMULATOR...... WAIT! I have an i7, 16 gb or RAM, SSD Hard drive, nothing else running except Tizen Studio AND it still takes A LONG TIME to load the emulator (like 30 + seconds).

Wait until you see the Tizen Home screen

THEN, Go to Build Project

THEN, Right click on Project File (Left/Top in Project Explorer window) and choose "Run As" Tizen Native Application.

Works every time for me. Ignore error that says cant open emulator because it is already running.

Hope this helps.